# Trying to calculate % of total by dimension

Tags: sql, postgresql

Right now I have a table that has 3 columns--Month, Store, Sales. I want to have an output that shows monthly market share by store but pivoted out. Have tried a few different methods and can manually output to excel to make it exactly how i want but would prefer a way to do so entirely in SQL. I've tried a few different approaches but they are not giving me the desired output. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Here is how my data is currently structured:
[image]

Here is how I would like the output to look:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with a correlated subquery, selecting each store's sales divided by the total sales for that year. Replace 'table' with your table name.

```
select store, month,
100*(sales/(select sum(sales) from table a where a.month = b.month)) as percentage 
from table b
```